# epoll with Queue for IPC

Tags: linux, ipc, epoll

Sorry for this silly question :), I'm using a queue for IPC between two threads, so I have one thread that sends if there is enough space in the queue, and the other thread is checking with infinite loop if there is a data available in the queue and receive it.

Is it possible to use epoll with this queue to check if there is a new data available on both sides? so the the sender checks for for EPOLLOUT and the receiver checks for the EPOLLIN?

Comment: Have you _tried_ it? Because if you didn't, you really should try it now. If you did and encountered problems, you should describe these problems. (I'm saying that because you seem to know the epoll-API already)

Comment: I'm trying to implement it but not sure how start, I know how to use it with file descriptor, not sure how to do that without it.

Comment: Which kind of queue are you using? I expected the queue to have an fd, if it doesn't, you cannot use it with epoll.